# select columns as rows and group the result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I ran into difficulties during my work on the query
I have a database of customers that looks like this

Customers

- ID
- CreatedTime

Fields

- Name
- UniqID

FieldsContent

- FieldUniqID
- Value
- CustomerID

in the end i wanna make a table that looks like this

- Customer.ID as CustomerID
- Field.Name as FirstName
- Field.Name as LastName
- Field.Name as Email
- Field.Name as Phone
- Customer.Created as Created

hope you help me find out how to do it,

i wrote it on using php as you can see:

```
$this->db->query('SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=10000000');
            $q = $this->db->select("GROUP_CONCAT(fieldsContent.Content SEPARATOR '|*|') AS Content,
                                    GROUP_CONCAT(fieldsContent.FieldID SEPARATOR '|*|') AS FieldID,
                                    customers.Created,
                                    customers.ID",false)
                          ->from('customers')
                          ->join('fieldsContent','fieldsContent.TypeID = customers.ID','left outer')
                          ->where(array('fieldsContent.TypeName' => 'customers',
                                        'customers.ID' => $id))
                          ->group_by('fieldsContent.TypeID')
                          ->order_by('customers.Created','DESC')
                          ->get();
            foreach($q->result() as $d){
                $field = explode('|*|',$d->FieldID);
                $content = explode('|*|',$d->Content);
                foreach($field as $k => $FieldID){   
                    $dd[$FieldID] = $content[$k];
                }
            }
```

but i need sql only without using php

Comment: [***Have you tried anything?***](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Hint: use `case ... end` for each column

Comment: Also, I think this kind of things can be better handled with a NoSQL database

Comment: *Don't post code in comments*. Edit your question and include it

Comment: @ADASein i want to make a view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like the following?

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=10000000;
CREATE VIEW <view_name> AS 
        ( 
                  SELECT    group_concat(fieldscontent.content separator '|*|') AS content,
                            group_concat(fieldscontent.fieldid separator '|*|') AS fieldid,
                            customers.created
                  FROM      customers 
                  LEFT JOIN fieldscontent
                  ON        fieldscontent.typeid = customers.id
                  GROUP BY  fieldscontent.typeid
                  ORDER BY  customers.created DESC
        )
```

and then you could just filter on the view!

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM      customers 
          LEFT JOIN fieldsContent 
          ON        fi' at line 6

Comment: @IlanFinkel if the above answers your question, which it does, would really appreciate it if you selected it as the answer! If not, was there something I maybe misinterpreted?